# Issues with a variable within Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to fix an error that Ive encountered with some code.

I tried editing the  model but nothing has worked. Also edited the controller, updated DB as well was made sure certain folders were in parent directory. Trying to figure out how to fix this error. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!!!

View:

```
<?php  
              if(file_exists('/assets/images/'.$user_data[0]->profile_pic) && isset($user_data[0]->profile_pic)){
              $profile_pic = $user_data[0]->profile_pic;
              }else{
              $profile_pic = 'user.png';}?>
              <center> <img class="thumb-image setpropileam" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/<?php echo isset($profile_pic)?$profile_pic:'user.png';?>" alt="User profile picture"></center>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {       
    function __construct(){            
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user_id =isset($this->session->get_userdata()['user_details'][0]->id)?$this->session->get_userdata()['user_details'][0]->users_id:'1';
    }

    /**
      * This function is used authenticate user at login
      */
    function auth_user() {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->db->where("is_deleted='0' AND (name='$email' OR email='$email')");
        $result = $this->db->get('users')->result();
        if(!empty($result)){       
            if (password_verify($password, $result[0]->password)) {       
                if($result[0]->status != 'active') {
                    return 'not_varified';
                }
                return $result;                    
            }
            else {             
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function is used to delete user
     * @param: $id - id of user table
     */
    function delete($id='') {
        $this->db->where('users_id', $id);  
        $this->db->delete('users'); 
    }

    /**
      * This function is used to load view of reset password and varify user too 
      */
    function mail_varify() {    
        $ucode = $this->input->get('code');     
        $this->db->select('email as e_mail');        
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('var_key',$ucode);
        $query = $this->db->get('cultured_codeignite');     
        $result = $query->row();   
        if(!empty($result->e_mail)){      
            return $result->e_mail;         
        }else{     
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
      * This function is used Reset password  
      */
    function ResetPpassword(){
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        if($this->input->post('password_confirmation') == $this->input->post('password')){
            $npass = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $data['password'] = $npass;
            $data['var_key'] = '';
            return $this->db->update('users',$data, "email = '$email'");
        }
    }

    /**
      * This function is used to select data form table  
      */
    function get_data_by($tableName='users', $value='', $colum='',$condition='') {  
        if((!empty($value)) && (!empty($colum))) { 
            $this->db->where($colum, $value);
        }
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($tableName);
        $query = $this->db->get('cultured_codeignite');
        return $query->result();
    }

    /**
      * This function is used to check user is alredy exist or not  
      */
    function check_exists($table='', $colom='',$colomValue=''){
        $this->db->where($colom, $colomValue);
        $res = $this->db->get($table)->row();
        if(!empty($res)){ return false;} else{ return true;}
    }

    /**
      * This function is used to get users detail  
      */
    function get_users($userID = '') {
        $this->db->where('is_deleted', '0');                  
        if(isset($userID) && $userID !='') {
            $this->db->where('users_id', $userID); 
        } else if($this->session->userdata('user_details')[0]->user_type == 'admin') {
            $this->db->where('user_type', 'admin'); 
        } else {
            $this->db->where('users.users_id !=', '1'); 
        }
        $result = $this->db->get('users')->result();
        return $result;
    }

    /**
      * This function is used to get email template  
      */
    function get_template($code){
        $this->db->where('code', $code);
        return $this->db->get('templates')->row();
    }

    /**
      * This function is used to Insert record in table  
      */
    public function insertRow($table, $data){
        $this->db->insert($table, $data);
        return  $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    /**
      * This function is used to Update record in table  
      */
    public function updateRow($table, $col, $colVal, $data) {
        $this->db->where($col,$colVal);
        $this->db->update($table,$data);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: user_data
>
> Filename: views/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 475
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home4/cultured/public_html/application/views/profile.php Line:
>   475 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home4/cultured/public_html/application/controllers/Login.php
>   Line: 47 Function: view
>
> File: /home4/cultured/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 475

Comment: Can you please put your controller code (function)

Comment: Where you set this `$user_data` variable in your code?

Comment: Hey there folks!! I tried to add the controller but its too long to fit :(

Answer (score 0):

put the code in you controller function in line number  `/home4/cultured/public_html/application/controllers/Login.php Line: 47`

The user data array should be there while returning the data to the view
If it is not there you will get the error

```
$data["user_data"] = ""; // Your user_data query result should be here
$this->load->view("profile", $data);
```

Comment: Hey and thank you!!! I followed your code but still got this error:Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object.....I feel that is not connecting to the DB but cant figure out where to connect to.